# Closed form for the partial sums of the Thue-Morse sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, combinatorics-on-words

Let $t_n$ denote the $n^{\rm th}$ element of the Thue-Morse sequence, i.e., $t_n$ begins
$$
0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,\ldots
$$
Now let $s_n$ denote the sequence defined by the partial sums of the $t_n$, so $s_n$ therefore begins
$$
0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, \ldots
$$
(entry [A115384](http://oeis.org/A115384) in the OEIS). Unfortunately the OEIS page does not list any closed forms for the $n^{\rm th}$ element of this sequence. Can such a closed form be found? Note that by ''closed form'' I mean a function that does not involve any partial sum.

Comment: Hmm, just something coming to mind. The difference to the sequence $u_n=n$ is the number of zeros below index $n$. It is known, that the Thue-morse sequence has no three concsecutive zeros or three consecutive one ("cube-free" sequence). So that number of zeros should be $n/2-1 \pm 1$ or so. So the partial sums $s_n$ should be $n/2$ with an error of at most $2$. Or so. (btw, I'd let begin the sequence at index $n=0$ then the number at $n$ gives the parity of bit-representation of its index $n$)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Yes. Asymptotically the number of $1$s is the same as the number of $0$s. So at any $n$, the difference should be at most $2$ given that no $111$ and no $000$ can exist. But that is still far from an *exact* value...

Comment: [Entry A115384](http://oeis.org/A115384) in the OEIS have been listing a closed form for this sum since [Tue Jun 01 03:00:00 EDT 2010](http://oeis.org/history/view?seq=A115384&v=5), "a(n)=floor((n+1)/2)+(1+(-1)^n)*(1-(-1)^ A000120(n))/4", where A000120(n) is the the binary weight of $n$ (a.k.a hammingweight of n, the bit count of n as in the accepted answer).

Comment: [At that entry on Tue Jun 01 03:00:00 EDT 2010](http://oeis.org/history/view?seq=A115384&v=5), the description, "Partial sums _of squares_ of Thue-Morse numbers" was wrong.  It was corrected in [the next version -- version 6](http://oeis.org/history/view?seq=A115384&v=6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get heuristically , for the sequence beginning with $n=0$ and $$T(n)=\text{Hammingweight}(n) \\
\qquad \qquad =\text{bitcount}(n) \pmod 2 \tag 1$$ for $s(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n T(n)$

$$ s(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n T(n) = \frac n2 + \begin{cases}
  T(n) &\text{if } n \equiv 0,2 \pmod 4 \\
  \frac 12 &\text{if } n \equiv 1,3 \pmod 4 \\ 
\end{cases} \tag 2$$
(modulo typing-error)....

Using $(-1)^n$ one can even make a oneliner from Eq (2).

---

```
   ----------------------------------------------
        n      T(n)     s(n)      n/2    + T(n)
   ----------------------------------------------
        0        0        0        0    
        4        1        3        2    
        8        1        5        4    
       12        0        6        6    
       16        1        9        8    
       20        0       10       10    
       24        0       12       12    
       28        1       15       14    
   ----------------------------------------------
        n      T(n)     s(n)      n/2      +1/2
   ----------------------------------------------
        1        1        1      1/2        1/2                    
        5        0        3      5/2        1/2                    
        9        0        5      9/2        1/2                    
       13        1        7     13/2        1/2                    
       17        0        9     17/2        1/2                    
       21        1       11     21/2        1/2                    
       25        1       13     25/2        1/2                    
       29        0       15     29/2        1/2                    
   ----------------------------------------------
        n      T(n)     s(n)      n/2     +T(n)
   ----------------------------------------------
        2        1        2        1    
        6        0        3        3    
       10        0        5        5    
       14        1        8        7    
       18        0        9        9    
       22        1       12       11    
       26        1       14       13    
       30        0       15       15    
   ----------------------------------------------
        n      T(n)     s(n)      n/2      +1/2
   ----------------------------------------------
        3        0        2      3/2        1/2                    
        7        1        4      7/2        1/2                    
       11        1        6     11/2        1/2                    
       15        0        8     15/2        1/2                   
       19        1       10     19/2        1/2                    
       23        0       12     23/2        1/2                    
       27        0       14     27/2        1/2                    
       31        1       16     31/2        1/2
```

Comment: That's amazing. I think the proof should not be too difficult, now that there is adequate inspiration. Thanks for your efforts!